# A guide to hacking IE8 into shape?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've finished making my website, but then I loaded it up in IE8. Big problems! For instance, a bunch of my `div` and `span` elements seem to be transparent (they should have coloured backgrounds), and floating elements don't work.

When I was developing my site, I had hoped I would just be able to ignore the older internet explorers - ie9 is standards compliant, and eventually everyone will end up using that. However, Microsoft are not releasing IE9 for XP, but people are going to be using that operating system for a long time still, I think. As such, I need to support IE8.

Does there exist a comprehensive list of all the things that IE8/ do wrong? Not something like [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), but a guide to the common issues with layout in IE8, and the hacks needed to fix them?

EDIT: The transparent elements thing seems to be somehow related to my use of css3pie.

Comment: Are you setting a !DOCTYPE on your page? And is IE8 running in compatability mode on your site, or not?

Comment: I'm using a doctype. I'm using IE9 on my PC, and just using the developer console to see how the site renders in IE7 and 8 mode.

Comment: While IE8 isn't the latest and greatest, it sounds like there may be something going on there. Your description at least doesn't sound like something it would typically have any problems with. Have you tried actually rendering it in IE8 and IE7 (Adobe Browserlabs or something)? Can you post some samples of problems with jsfiddle.net or something?

Comment: Well, if your problems are related to javascript libraries, then you're probably not using them correctly.  The thing is, that javascript is going under the covers and changing everything, making it hard to pinpoint the real problem.

Comment: @MystereMan Yeah, I figured that. The javascript stuff in this case seems to be just related to some confusion surrounting `position:absolute` objects and background gradients, I resolved it. My remaining problem is to do with floats & clearfix: in particular, that I can't get that to work in IE8. It's kind of hard to refine the core of the problem down into a viable SO question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using conditional classes to target specific fixes for specific versions of IE. This is from **[Paul Irish's HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate)**:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

With these comments you can specify something like:

```
.ie7 #container {margin-left:-1px;}
```

And it would only change your `#container` margin on IE7.

If those don't work, post some of your code and people might be able to point out some incompatibilities.